# Finding True value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a table called DueAction and it has an reference of DueEmployeeDetail.I need to update is_confimed column of DueEmployeeDetail only when all the entries of DueAction table having reference of DueEmployeeDetail table is true.For eg. if there are 5 entries and only 3 is true then is_confirmed must not update to true.

```html
in model i have written this :-

def is_exist(due_employee_detail)
   # byebug
   flag = 0
    DueAction.exists?(is_confirm: true,due_employee_detail_id: due_employee_detail)
    flag
  end

in controller i have wriien this:-

  if @due_action.is_exist(@due_action.due_employee_detail_id)
  DueEmployeeDetail.where(id: @due_action.due_employee_detail_id).update_all(is_confirmed: true)
  else
  end
  
  but its not working.Its checking only true not checking whether all are true or not.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are comfortable with your DB models design.
If I understood it well, DueAction has a reference of DueEmployeeDetail. You better don't do that in your controllers, you can move this logic to your models.

```
class DueEmployeeDetail < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :confirm!, if: :has_all_due_actions_confirmed?

  def has_all_due_actions_confirmed?
    due_actions.all?(&:is_confirmed)
  end

  def confirm!
    self.is_confirmed = true
  end


end
```

Comment: and how may i  access this method in controller??

Comment: This method is contained in DueEmployeeDetails "life cycle". Whenever you call save on it, this callbacks will automatically run.

`due_employee_detail = DueEmployeeDetail.find(some_id)
due_employee_detail.save` 

will trigger the mentioned logic